# im trying to make a window hook in python 3.8.10

Tags: python

im trying to make a simulation of a troijan called "memz troijan destructive" and the problem is in the playload.

heres a bit of my playload code

```
from win32gui import *
from win32ui import *
from win32api import *
import time

hwnd = GetDesktopWindow( )
hdc2 = GetWindowDC(0)
x2 = GetSystemMetrics(0)
y2 = GetSystemMetrics(0)

def tunnel_effect():
    for i in range(0, 50):
        StretchBlt(hdc2, 25, 25, x2 - 50, y2 - 50, hdc2, 0, 0, x2, 0x00CC002)
        
def paintinvert():
    for i in range(0, 7):
        PatBlt(hdc2, 0, 0, x2, y2, 589313)
        time.sleep(2)



tunnel_effect()
paintinvert()
```

and heres the result

```
line 13, in tunnel_effect
    StretchBlt(hdc2, 25, 25, x2 - 50, y2 - 50, hdc2, 0, 0, x2, 0x00CC002)
TypeError: StretchBlt() takes exactly 11 arguments (10 given)
```

is there an argument that i am missing?

Answer (score 1):

yes, you need 11 args.
please refer to the MS docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-stretchblt

Comment: that didnt work

Comment: can you tell me what arg is missing?

Comment: @MEMZ, it is impossible to tell which one you forgot, since here you do not use named arguments. Please go through the documentation and check each argument and map it to your args. Then you can identify which one is missing

Comment: k i hpe it works